# Set in immutable Map without override the previous value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

i'm dispatching an action which sets in the state inside a map an id for a person. My code in the reducer is like this:

```
const customerSessionReducer = (customerSession = Map(), action) => {
  if (!action) {
    return customerSession;
  }
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_CUSTOMER_SESSION:
      return customerSession
        .set('customerSession', action.payload.customerID);
    default:
      return Map();
  }
};
```

When i'm dispatching the action the customerSessionPart of the state is updated without holding the previous value. I want somehow create a Map whose keys contains the customerIDs. I don't want to lose the previous customerIDs
Do you have any idea of how to achieve this?
For example suppose i dispatch an action for the first time, My customersession has the customerId. When i'm dispatching again my Map is not like {customerID, customerID} but it is lossing the previous value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

calling `map.set(key, value)` will replace the value on the provided `key`, you have a couple of options:

have a list as the value you are replacing

```
const previousList = customerSession.get('customerSession');
 //...

 case SET_CUSTOMER_SESSION:
    return customerSession
      .set('customerSession', previousList.push(action.payload.customerID));
```

use the customerID as the key on that `Map`

```
case SET_CUSTOMER_SESSION:
    return customerSession
      .set(action.payload.customerID, 'some-other-value?');
```

if you don't need to store any other value and you want to have unique values in your store, use a `Set` instead of a map

```
const customerSessionReducer = (customerSession = Set(), action) => {
  if (!action) {
    return customerSession;
  }

  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_CUSTOMER_SESSION:
      return customerSession
        .add(action.payload.customerID);
    default:
      return Set();
  }
};
```

Comment: I can also use update. What of those two would you suggest?

Comment: @user7334203 I would recommend the third option

Comment: I can't work with Set. It;s mandatory for my project to use only Map :(

Comment: @user7334203 - option 2 then